# How to properly await for the resolved value of an ES6 Javascript async function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Why do these two code snippets output differently? In the first one, when I console out, I get pending Promises (when I want the actual value).

```
(() => {
  let message = {
    actions: [{}]
  };
  message.actions = message.actions.map(async action => {
    action.result = {};
    action.result.startAt = await "whatever";
    return action;
  });

  console.log(message);
})();
```

And in this second code snippet, I get the actual resolved value...

```
( async () => {
  let message = {
   actions: [{}]
  };                                                                                                
  message.actions[0].result = {};
  message.actions[0].result.startAt = await "whatever";

  console.log(message);
})();
```

Comment: async functions return a promise when executed, their resolved values are available in `then()` callbacks. So your first snippet is just making an array of promises. Your second snippet is simply logging a object inside an async function, not logging the result of the async function.

Comment: `async` is not used at first example

Comment: Right, but how can I get the console.log to fully wait for the resolved values? In my actual code, the console.log is a push to an SNS queue, and I get "Pending Promise" as the value.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the console.log is a push"_? Can you include actual code at Question?

Comment: @pjb, your first code is basically mapping an array of objects into an array of promises. Besides `await` will stop execution right there and won't resume until next job tick, that means your `console.log` will never be able to see whatever you `await`. Unless you `console.log` after the `await` (or through `then` of each promise)

Comment: @minusfour so how to properly `await` in this case? Do I have to build some complex `Promise.all` as someone else suggested?

Answer (score 1):

If the procedure is asynchronous you can use `Promise.all()` or a `for` loop to await each element of `message.actions` to return a `Promise` value

```js
(async () => {
  let message = {
    actions: [{}]
  };
  message.actions = await Promise.all(message.actions.map(async(action) => {
    action.result = {};
    action.result.startAt = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), "whatever"));
    return action;
  }));

  console.log(message);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

First case:

You started async task and without waiting for it completion requesting value of the task (not sure why).

Second case:

You fill the structure and print it immediately so it works.

Yet `await "whatever";` is just `"whatever"`